# bootstrap tooltip not refreshing on deselection

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap multiselect for multiselect box. i fire ajax calls for building drop downs and then i use :

```
$(element).multiselect('rebuild');
```

for building the bootstrap thing. problem is when i select anything and then hover on the button it show correctly the names which have been select in drop down as tool tip but when i deselect anything it doesn't. the previous selection is being show in tool tip.

Any idea why this is happening.

html :

```
<div>
<span>Data </span> <select data-placeholder="Data"
multiple="multiple" class="multiselect" id="data"style="width: 100%;">
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i just found out the solutions for this. there is a attribute in multiselect js "nonSelectedText" which was commented. actually you can customize this to have your own message.